# How free AVAssetExportSession because It's busy?

Tags: swift

In my project, I need to edit a video. I cut (in time) and crop (in size) to generate a new video.
I use the AVAssetExportSession to make it.

The code works well but I get an error after twenty to try.

```
func crop(toUrl cropUrl: URL, ratio: Ratio, _ completion: @escaping (_ outputUrl: URL?) -> Void) {
    guard let videoTrack = self.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else { return }

    let composition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    composition.renderSize = CGSize(width: (videoTrack.naturalSize.height * ratio.width) + 1.0, height: videoTrack.naturalSize.height)
    composition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(roundf(videoTrack.nominalFrameRate)))

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: self.duration)

    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -(videoTrack.naturalSize.width - videoTrack.naturalSize.height * ratio.width) / 2, y: 0.0)
    layerInstruction.setTransform(transform, at: CMTime.zero)

    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
    composition.instructions = [instruction]

    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: self, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1280x720)!
    exportSession.videoComposition = composition
    exportSession.outputURL = cropUrl
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov

    exportSession.exportAsynchronously( completionHandler: { () -> Void in
        guard exportSession.status == .completed else {
            print(exportSession.error.debugDescription)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(nil)
            }

            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(exportSession.outputURL)
        }
    })
}
```

The error:

*AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11839 "Cannot Decode" and NSLocalizedFailureReason=The decoder required for this media is busy., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Stop any other actions that decode media and try again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Decode*

So how can I access the data still in process in AVAssetExportSession ? Can I free them and how? Is there another way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you run multiple сrop() function at the same time? If so, I would suggest you make a queue with max concurrent operation equal 1 and wrap func crop to operation.

Comment: Actually, I do crop one by one. I'm waiting to get the result of my function crop() to start a new crop if necessary.